# Customer Address custom attribute not showing front end in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, customer-address

I am trying to create and save the Customer Address custom attribute for these I have created the module and it's successfully created and showing backend (adminhtml), But frontend not showing.

My code is:

```
<?php

namespace Learning\CA\Setup;


use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;



/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.1.0', '<')) {

            $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer_address');
            $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

            $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
            $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

            $customerSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', 'dummy_nav_customer_id', [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Nav Customer ID',
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => false,
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'sort_order' => 1000,
                'position' => 1000,
                'system' => 0,
            ]);

            $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer_address', 'dummy_nav_customer_id')
                ->addData([
                    'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                    'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                    'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_address_edit', 'customer_register_address'],
                ]);
            $attribute->save();
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }

}
```

[image]

And it's showing while debugging my code, after saving customer address see below pic.

[image]

Why it's not showing `frontend`? My code is wrong?

Comment: Are you have this code in github?
I have the same problem but I can not solve. Sorry about my english, I don't write very well.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/137054)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Customer Address edit form won't automatically generate custom attribute.
You have to override template file `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/address/edit.phtml` to show it in `frontend`.

E.g., override template in theme:

- Copy `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/address/edit.phtml` to  `app/design/frontend/[Vendor] /[theme]/Magento_Customer/templates/address/edit.phtml`
- Add this to new template:

  ```
  <div class="field dummy_nav_customer_id">
          <label class="label" for="dummy_nav_customer_id"><span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Nav Customer ID')) ?></span></label>
          <div class="control">
              <input type="text" name="dummy_nav_customer_id" value="<?php echo $this->helper(\Magento\Framework\EscapeHelper::class)->escapeHtmlAttr((!is_null($block->getAddress()->getCustomAttribute('dummy_nav_customer_id')) ? $block->getAddress()->getCustomAttribute('dummy_nav_customer_id')->getValue() : '')) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->helper(\Magento\Framework\EscapeHelper::class)->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Nav Customer ID')) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper(\Magento\Framework\EscapeHelper::class)->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper(\Magento\Customer\Helper\Address::class)->getAttributeValidationClass('dummy_nav_customer_id')) ?>" id="dummy_nav_customer_id">
          </div>
      </div>
  ```

Comment: I am getting fatal error : Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getValue() on null in

Comment: @SheshgiriAnvekar If your custom attribute is not set, ```getCustomAttribute``` will return ```null```, you should check it first then ```getValue()``` if not null

Comment: I am also getting same error getValue(), while adding new address at frontend. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated solution which I have applied and worked fine for me.
First you have to override `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/address/edit.phtml` file in your theme then add below code in it.Please replace `custom_attribute` by your own attribute code.

```
<div class="field custome_attribute">
<label class="label" for="custome_attribute"><span><?php echo $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('custome_attribute'); ?></span></label>
<div class="control">
    <input type="text" name="custome_attribute" value="<?= ($block->getAddress()->getCustomAttribute('custome_attribute') === null) ? "" : $block->getAddress()->getCustomAttribute('custome_attribute')->getValue(); ?>" title="<?php echo __('custome_attribute') ?>" class="input-text" id="custome_attribute">
</div>
</div>
```

Hope this will work for you.
Thank you. :)